# How can I pass an Apache POI function to the Java Comparator class in a Groovy script

Tags: excel, groovy, apache-poi, soapui

Attempting to perform a sorting of the rows in an Excel file based on the value in a column in SoapUI via a Groovy script since POI doesn't have any in-built row sorting functions.  One method of doing the sorting I've come across uses the Comparator method. But the `Comparator.comparing()` requires a "keyExtractor" function to be passed into it.  The keyExtractor function is the function that would return a `Comparable` sort key.  (Ref: [Comparator.comparing() method discription](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-))

Tried to pass in the function as shown in the example of that document :

```
    Row tempRow = rows.get(1) //Header row exists in the data
    Comparator<Row> sortByColumn = Comparator.comparing((tempRow.getCell(colNum)::getStringCellValue))
    rows.sort(Comparator.comparing(sortByColumn))
```

which throws an error in SoapUI Groovy saying that the `::` is an unexpected token.  Using the `.&` operator in place of the `::` throws back a

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.util.Comparator.comparing() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.Comparator$$Lambda$225/23399299) values: [java.util.Comparator$$Lambda$225/23399299@748b00]
```

Any suggestions.??

Thanks

Comment: If you're in Groovy, why not pass in a closure, eg `{ cell -> cell.getStringCellValue() }` or similar? Take care on cell types though!

Comment: switching to ```Comparator<Row> sortByColumn = Comparator.comparing({cell -> cell.getStringCellValue()})``` again gave that MissingMethodException error.  Besides, how would I then specify which column it is sorting by when I use 'cell'.?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Assuming you have an `int` containing the column number of interest, try something like `{ row -> def c = row.getCell(wantedColumnIndex); c ? c.getStringCellValue() : "" }`

Comment: in order to use `::` you need Groovy 3.+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparator.comparing is a factory method that is used to generate a comparator from a lambda or method reference that returns the "sort key".  You can also create a comparator class using an anonymous inner class or a Groovy closure.  However, Groovy offers extension methods for sorting that use closures directly in much the same way that Comparator.comparing works.

```
int colNum = ... // the column to sort on
// use "tail()" to exclude the header row from the sorted result
def sorted = rows.tail().sort { row -> row.getCell(colNum).stringCellValue }
```

Comment: POI uses ```cell.getStringCellValue()``` to return the cell's string contents.  But when I tried that code, it throws up this error : ```groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: getStringCellValue for class: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell error```.  Had to have the ```()``` at the end of that.

But the list still didn't get sorted at all.

Comment: My bad, I was looking at the wrong place for the sorted results.  It's working now. Thanks